# Numpy Arrays M Dimentions Elementwise Multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Problem Explanation**

I have four numpy arrays

A of  n dimentions

B of  m  dimentions

C of o dimentions

D of n dimentions

I have also a list of indexex for each dimention

```
Aindexes = Ia[Ia1, Ia2, … , Ian]

Bindexes = Ib[Ib1,Ib2, …. , Ibm]

Cindexes = Ic[Ia1, Ic1, Ic2,  …. , Ico]

Dindexes = Ia[Ia1, Ia2, … Ian]
```

Ineed to perform three operations, but I need it to behave differently depending on the matching of the indexes:

```
R = A * B  (all different indexes) =
RIndexes [Ia1, Ia2, … , Ian, Ib1, Ib2, … Ibm] 
Rvalues it’s an elementwise multiplication of all elements

R = A * C (Some indexes equal)
RIndexes [Ia1, Ia2, … Iam, Ic1, Ic2, … Ico]
Rvalues it’s an elementwise multiplication of all elements not repeating the indexes that are equal 

R = A * D (all equal indexes) 
Rindexes [Ia1, Ia2, … Iam] 
Rvalues = A[Iam] * D[Iamij]
```

**Practical example for tables of 2 dimentions**

```
A [Index1[3],Index2[2]] = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]

B [Index4[3], Index3[2]] = [[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]]

C [Index1[3], Index3[2]] = [[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]]

D[Index1[3],Index2[2]] = [[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]]
```

**A*B**

*Evaluating by some indexes*

```
R[Index1[3],Index2[2 = 1],Index4[3],Index3[2 = 1]] = [[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]

R[Index1[3],Index2[2 = 2],Index4[3],Index3[2 = 1]] = [[6,6,6],[6,6,6],[6,6,6]]

R[Index1[3],Index2[2 = 1],Index4[3],Index3[2 = 2]] = [[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]]

R[Index1[3],Index2[2 = 2],Index4[3],Index3[2 = 2]] = [[8,8,8],[8,8,8],[8,8,8]]
```

**Total**

```
RIndex1[3],Index2[2],Index4[3],Index3[2]] = [[[[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],[[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]]],[[[6,6,6],[6,6,6],[6,6,6]],[[[8,8,8],[8,8,8],[8,8,8]]]]]
```

**A*C**

*Evaluating by some indexes*

```
R[Index1[3],Index2[2],Index3[2 = 1]] = [[3,6],[3,6],[3,6]]

R[Index1[3],Index2[2],Index3[2 = 2]] = [[4,8],[4,8],[4,8]]
```

*Total*

```
R[Index1[3],Index2[2],Index3[2]] = [[[3,6],[3,6],[3,6]]
,[[4,8],[4,8],[4,8]]]
```

**A*D**

```
R[Index1[3],Index2[2]] = [[1,4],[1,4],[1,4]]
```

My question is how to implement this with numpy for m dimentions ?

Comment: We need some examples that we can copy-n-paste. That is actual arrays for `A,B...` and `Index1,...`.  Your requirements are too complicated to quickly visualize.

Comment: I'll create an example in python and attach it to my post, thanks :)